# How to turn bluetooth off as default when booting ubuntu?

Tags: bluetooth, settings

I seldom use bluetooth, so I want the default status of the bluetooth is off. However I don't find any option in GUI setting application about that. Is there any way (for example, write a config file, or use command with parameters) to set bluetooth off as default?